# if <img src=""> but no image

Tags: php, image

When trying to display image that's adress doesn't exist you will see default browsers "no image" badge.

How to change it to default "no-image.png" placeholder?

```
echo "<img src='http://www.google.com/trolol.png'>"; //for example
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `onerror` attribute, example:

```
<img src="" onerror="this.src = 'no-image.png';" alt="" />
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kNgYK/

Comment: OK why this fails: `<?php
$error = "onerror='this.src = \'http://userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow2.png\'';";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
 echo "<img src='http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/3716_obj_sprite.gif?id=" . $i . "' alt='ID " . $i . "' title='ID " . $i . "'" . $error . "/>";
}
?>`?

Comment: Neat solution, better than the accepted one imo :) Thnx!

Answer (score 5):

```
<img src='http://www.google.com/trolol.png' onerror="this.src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png'">​
```

sample http://jsfiddle.net/UPdZh/1/

> The onerror event is triggered if an error occurs while loading an
>   external file (e.g. a document or an image).

**Syntax**

```
<element onerror="SomeJavaScriptCode">
```

http://wap.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$filename = 'http://www.google.com/trolol.png';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "<img src='".$filename."'>";
} else {
    echo "<img src='no-image.png'>";
}
?>
```

Comment: OK WTF why it fails, when your code not: `<?php
$i = 2;
$filename = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/3716_obj_sprite.gif?id=" . $i;
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "<img src=" . $filename . " />";
} else {
    echo "NO IMAGE";
}
?>`

Comment: Just forgot your ' ' :)
<?php $i = 2; 
$filename = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/3716_obj_sprite.gif?id=" . $i;
 if (file_exists($filename)) 
 { echo "<img src='" . $filename . "' />"; }
 else { echo "NO IMAGE"; } ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$filename = 'http://www.google.com/trolol.png';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: This code fails, have you tried it on remote file like "https://www.google.pl/logos/2012/haring-12-hp.png"?

Comment: hi this one will work. <?
// Set the URL you want to connect to
$url = "http://img2.meetupstatic.com/906521611995523788/img/header/logo.png";

// Check to see if the file exists by trying to open it for read only
if (fopen($url, "r")) {

 echo "File Exists";

} else {

 echo "Can't Connect to File";

}

?>

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for a PHP solution:

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
  echo "i_exist.jpg";
} else {
  echo "fallback.jpg";
}
```

IMPORTANT: Works only for local files, not for remote ones! Thanks to Szymon for the comment!

Comment: by the way the (fantastic) onerror="..." solution can kill older versions of opera.

Comment: This code fails, have you tried it on remote file like "https://www.google.pl/logos/2012/haring-12-hp.png"?